# Simple expression for a cumulative sum over list

Tags: python

I have a Python array, and I want to write a single expression that returns an array with sum of all previous numbers. 
For example we have:

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
```

And my function should return :

```
[1, 3, 6, 10]
```

I know that it's possible to make it with simple loop or even recursivly, but is it possible to make in one line? 
Something like:

```
def converter(arr):
    arr1 = [x + y for x,y in arr ]
    return arr1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.2, you can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> arr = [1,2,3,4]
>>> list(accumulate(arr))
[1, 3, 6, 10]
```

Comment: thank you, it's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: @BedrosKarapetyan Please just use numpy `import numpy as np; np.asarray(arr).cumsum()`

Comment: @displayname, `itertools` is in the standard library, and `numpy` is not. You don't need a hammer to squish a mosquito.

Comment: @randomir Well, true, but show me one script of yours that doesn't use `numpy` anyway :P

Comment: @displayname, feel free to browse over my GitHub. Almost none of those scripts use `numpy`. [PickTheRightToolForTheJob](http://wiki.c2.com/?PickTheRightToolForTheJob).